# NGINX Log request on specific URI

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to log all request coming from a specific URI. For example, I want to log all request coming from http://test123.com/api/xxxxxxx, with /api.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name xxxxxxx;
root /usr/share/nginx/app/public;
index index.php index.html;

location /api{
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/test.access.log  main;
 }
}
```

This code successfully logs the request but returned an error

```
open() "/usr/share/nginx/app/public/api" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

location /api is that location exist file and dir. Please check properly files.

Comment: I am using url routing. So how can i be able to do this?